# Who is the "Seed of the Serpent" spoken of in Genesis 3?

Tags: exegesis, genesis, satan

In Genesis 3, God curses the serpent Satan in the following words:

> **The Lord God said to the serpent**, “Because you have done this, cursed
>   are you more than all cattle, and more than every beast of the field;
>   pn your belly you will go, and dust you will eat all the days of your
>   life; And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between
>   **your seed** and her Seed; He shall bruise you on the head, and you
>   shall bruise him on the heel.”  Genesis 3:14-15 NASB

Most Christians understand the Seed of the woman to be referring to Jesus, who was uniquely born of woman.  However, it seems unclear who the seed of the serpent is.

To whom exactly is this referring?  I'm not sure a particular tradition matters here, but I'm most interested in a perspective that at the very least views the Scriptures as the divine Word of God (a biblical literalist), but again, I'm not sure other perspectives would really impact an understanding of this too much.

Comment: The most literal interpretation is that the seed of Eve is all human beings, and the seed of the serpent is all snakes.

Comment: @ChrisSunami In Galatians 3:16, Paul notes that the promise to Abraham's "Seed" indicated a single descendant--not all descendants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking to the Pharisees, Jesus said,

> Ye are of your father the devil, and the lusts of your father ye will
>   do. He was a murderer from the beginning, and abode not in the truth,
>   because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh
>   of his own: for he is a liar, and the father of it.
>
> And because I tell you the truth, ye believe me not.
>
> Which of you convinceth me of sin? And if I say the truth, why do ye
>   not believe me?
>
> He that is of God heareth God's words: ye therefore hear them not,
>   because ye are not of God.
>
> *John 8:44-47*

Those who do not do the will of God, but live in sin are the devil's seed.

> He that is not with me is against me; and he that gathereth not with
>   me scattereth abroad.
>
> *Matthew 12:30*

There are only two teams. Those who are the seed of the woman, and those who are the seed of the serpent. Those who are with God and those who are against God. There is no neutrality.

Comment: This is also in agreement with the Bible commentaries on the verse at [Bible Hub](http://biblehub.com/genesis/3-15.htm), backing up that this is a commonly held view, and not just a personal interpretation of the verses.

Answer (score 3):

Since "seed" is a singular, just like Christ (singular) being the seed of the woman, it seems natural to think that the seed of the serpent is the antichrist, or the beast from Revelation, who is attempting to gain the worship of the world.

Comment: *it seems natural to think*. Can you validate it with the Scriptures?

Comment: This harmonizes with Revelation 12 and 13 where we have The Great Red Dragon (who is identified with "The Serpent of old") which is followed up by the Beast out of the sea (commonly identified as the Antichrist). Revelation 12 recaps Genesis 3 from a broader cosmic perspective and ties it with the Satan's last days. The Battle between The Male Child (The Woman's Seed) and Satan and his minions (seeds?) appears reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, the most literal interpretation is that the seed (in the Hebrew, a collective noun, [Strongs 2233](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/2233.htm)) of Eve is all human beings, and the seed of the serpent is all snakes. A particular interpretation postulates that the seed of Eve, as intended here, is Jesus alone, but there is nothing in this passage to suggest that any other meaning was intended as the seed of the serpent, especially a meaning that involves the devil.

We can see this when we look at the detail: the serpent, an animal, is cursed more than other animals; will go on his belly (as snakes do, but not the devil); will eat dust (as snakes almost seem to do). There will be enmity between the serpent's descendants and Eve's descendants, who will smash the head of any snake they find, because snakes will bite the feet of men.

Answer (score 0):

Every human birthed into this world is spiritually contaminated with the seed of Satan.
Rom 5:18  Therefore as by the offense of one judgment came upon all men to condemnation;

All natural human beings are incompatible with God.
Joh 3:3  Jesus answered and said unto him, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God.

God sowed His seed (word seed): Gen 2:17  "But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die."

Satan sowed his seed (word seed): Gen 3:4  "And the serpent said unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:"

The spirit beings of type man (Adam) received the seed of Satan and rejected the seed of God. They were spiritually birthed from Satan.

How do we know the Word is the seed?
Mar 4:14  The sower soweth the word.

Satan is the legal owner of the natural man.
2Co 4:3  But if our gospel be hid, it is hid to them that are lost: 
2Co 4:4  In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not,

**Good News.**

God brought new Seed "her seed".
Joh 1:1  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 
Joh 1:14  And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth.

Jesus told us that he brought new Seed.
Joh 17:8  For I have given unto them the words which thou gavest me; and they have received them, and have known surely that I came out from thee, and they have believed that thou didst send me.

Every human can now escape from captivity through a new birth.
1Pe 1:23  Being born again, not of corruptible seed, but of incorruptible, by the word of God, which liveth and abideth forever.

This new man is a new creation.
2Co 5:17  Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

This new man is taken out of darkness and placed into God's kingdom.
1Pe 2:9  But ye are a chosen generation, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a peculiar people; that ye should show forth the praises of him who hath called you out of darkness into his marvelous light:

Thus:

The serpent's seed are those born into this world and is not yet born from above.

The woman's seed are those born into this world **and** born from above (a spiritual re birth).

Joh 3:5  Jesus answered, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God. 
Joh 3:6  That which is born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit.

How are you birthed a second time?
Rom 10:8  But what saith it? The word is nigh thee, even in thy mouth, and in thy heart: that is, the word of faith, which we preach; 
Rom 10:9  That if thou shalt confess with thy mouth the Lord Jesus, and shalt believe in thine heart that God hath raised him from the dead, thou shalt be saved. 
Rom 10:10  For with the heart man believeth unto righteousness; and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation. 
Rom 10:11  For the Scripture saith, Whosoever believeth on him shall not be ashamed.

Comment: Welcome Judah!  This answer could use some improvement, both in formatting and to make it focus more directly on the question being asked.  This site is a bit different from others: please take a minute to learn [how this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and review [how to write a good, supported answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

Genesis 3:15
  And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed: it shall bruise thy head and thou shalt bruise his heel. 
Mt.13:38
The field is the world; the good seed are the children of the kingdom, but the tares are the children of the wicked one.

John 8:44
Ye are of your father the devil, and the lust of your father will ye do----.

Acts 13:10
O full of all subtlety and all mischief, thou child of the devil----.

1 John 3:10
In this the children of God are manifest and the children of the devil: ----

After the curse Eve gave birth to two sons, one good, one evil and the simple result was murder, the bad murdered the good. So began the story of man---. 
Jesus had much to say about Children of the devil, even in parables and it should be plain and simple to accept His words. I have read some outlandish interpretations of Genesis 3:15, I am both surprised and dismayed The Bible has been misinterpreted in so many ways. This is an allegory--this applies to that and not to this.
My eyes and my heart are focused on the Word of God and I find to let scripture interpret scripture and let the Holy Spirit guide me in understanding. 
Thank you. KB

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.